# How do I push objects to an array in apps script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, slack-api

I'm using the admin.analytics.getFile method to retrieve some data for an app I'm building.
I can't figure out in apps script how to push the result of an api call, which I've formatted, to an array for further manipulation.

I'm at a stage where I have each user's data, on one row per user in a sheet as a result of some scripting. My thoughts were to try to loop through the sheet, wrap each cell in curly bracers to make objects (each user's data is stored in one cell), and then push each object to an array.

```
function convertSplitDataToObjectArray (departmentNumbers,splitData) {

  //convert split data to object array, return splitDataAsObjectArray;
  var placeholderArray = [];

  for (let i=1; i<=363; i++) {

    placeholderArray.push(raw.getRange(i,1).getValue());

  }
  
  var splitDataAsObjectArray = placeholderArray.map((x) => {

    return {x};

  });

};
```

This is what I've come up with. I could be being incredibly nooby, but I had expected {x} to simply wrap each string in curly bracers. Instead it returns `{x="team_id":"17291125", etc etc... }`

My goal would be for the contents of each cell to become objects - they are currently strings, in a `key:value` format. I feel like I'm not miles away from something, but any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Sample source data: "team_id":"redacted","date":"2024-01-31","user_id":"redacted","email_address":"redacted","is_guest":false,"is_billable_seat":true,"is_active":true,"is_active_ios":false,"is_active_android":true,"is_active_desktop":false,"reactions_added_count":1,"messages_posted_count":7,"channel_messages_posted_count":1,"files_added_count":0,"is_active_apps":false,"is_active_workflows":false,"is_active_slack_connect":false,"total_calls_count":0,"slack_calls_count":0,"slack_huddles_count":0,"search_count":18,"date_claimed":1595412410
// This is what raw.getRange(i,1).getValue() returns. Each of these is a string.

Sample existing result: {x="team_id":"redacted",.....}

Sample desired result - an array of objects of the form: {
"team_id":"redacted","date":"2024-01-31","user_id":"U01AQD7JT71","email_address":"example@mail.com",...}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include **1.** sample source data, **2.** sample existing result, **3.** sample desired result. Currently you lack #1 & #3. Existing #2  may already be adequate depending on #1 &. #3,

Comment: Provide `console.log(x)`. You're probably looking for `JSON.parse()` though.

Comment: 1. Use `console` and not `Logger`. 2. Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.

Comment: This is apps script,  my apologies for not making that clear, and hence my concern with the size of the object being logged to the console. I'm therefore not able to `console.log(x)`. Thanks

Comment: @JudahHooper I'm not misunderstanding. It is clear you are using apps script.  Therefore my advise to use `console.log` is valid. It's also better to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(x))` 2. It's unclear where exactly your sample ends and therefore my advise to use code fences to highlight properly. Also avoid `...` in samples. Redaction is fine, `....` is not.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is `"team_id":"17291125"`, then you can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it to a object.

```
return JSON.parse(`{`+ x +`}`);
```

Comment: @JudahHooper I still expect it to work. If it doesn't, please provide better sample, which is complete( without `...`s)

Comment: unfortunately this returns `SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 545` in the console.

is this potentially due to the size of the object the console is trying to log? I've edited the question to include a full sample data.

Comment: @JudahHooper It means the string isn't a valid json object, specifically, at 545th character, something that isn't  valid for a object is present. It might not even be for all the 363 items, but just one of the items... you need to debug... see [mcve] for debugging tips.